# why factory method for creating Calendar Instance

Tags: java, factory-pattern, java.util.calendar

Wanted to know more about `Calendar.getInstance()`. I can create Date instance with constroctor, but why not a Calendar instance? Why `Calendar` designed to use a factory method and why it has been abstract class.

Please share the reason behind it.

My Question is very simple:
If we have new operator on Date class, why not for Calender. what was the idea behind a static method to create instance.

Many Thanks,

Comment: I am really not getting the answer for this question. People who closed, can you answer me. REASON behind choosing static method getInstance in Calender.

Answer (score 3):

There are different Calendar implementations. Calendard.getInstance() is locale sensitive and returns the suitable implementation for the country of your default locale.

The documentation says: "The Calendar returned is based on the current time in the default time zone with the default locale."

According to source code you get a BuddhistCalendar for language "th" and country "TH" or a JapaneseImperialCalendar for Japan with variant "JP". Otherwise you get a GregorianCalendar instance.

You are free to create a GregorianCalendar instance with its constructor.